# How to merge two 4D matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I plan to merge two matrix using matlab.
A is M*N*3*P  and B is M*N*3*Q.
how to get a matrix, which is M*N*3* (P+Q)?
Is there a function available?

Comment: `C = cat(4, A, B)`, see MATLAB's "Concatenation Methods"

Comment: @MatthiasW. make it an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The function you are looking for is called [`cat`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) - "Concatenate arrays along specified dimension".

> `C = cat(dim, A, B)` concatenates the arrays `A` and `B` along array
>   the dimension specified by dim. The dim argument must be a real,
>   positive, integer value.

In your case `C = cat(4, A, B)` does the trick. The `dim=4` as `A` and `B` are both 4-dimensional and you want to concatenate in the 4th dimension.

**Example:**

```
A = ones(4,5,3,7);
B = zeros(4,5,3,17);
C = cat(4, A, B);

>> size(A)
ans =

     4     5     3     7
>> size(B)
ans =

     4     5     3    17
>> size(C)
ans =

     4     5     3    24
```